# How do I set test.testLogging.showStandardStreams to true from the command line?

Tags: gradle

It is convenient to debug some of external libraries and even internal code while writing unit tests by reviewing the logging on stdout.

While I can add `test.testLogging.showStandardStreams = true` to the build.graddle file, I'd rather do something less permanent, such as setting this flag from the command line execution of gradle.

I've tried several approaches, none seem to work:

```
gradle test -Dtest.testLogging.showStandardStreams=true
gradle test -Ptest.testLogging.showStandardStreams=true
```

And other variations of those options by changing the property string. Nothing seems to do the trick.

How do I set `test.testLogging.showStandardStreams=true` from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in way to set build model properties from the command line. You'll have to make the build script query a system or project property that gets passed in via `-D` or `-P`, respectively.

Comment: This may have been true when the answer was added, but it is possible now.  See my answer below

Answer (score 5):

Just use environment variables:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = (System.getenv('PRINTF_DEBUG') != null)
}
```

Now run your test case like this:

```
PRINTF_DEBUG=1 ./gradlew test --tests=com.yourspace.yourtest
```

This will run enable console output *and* just run one single test case. You often not want to enable console output for the entire test suite because of the noise generated.

Answer (score 4):

You can override it like this

```
gradle -Doverride.test.testLogging.info.showStandardStreams=true test
```

or you can add this to your `gradle.properties` either in the project or in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
systemProp.override.test.testLogging.info.showStandardStreams=true
```

Comment: I was NOT able to get this to work too. 
BTW I also tried a command like this (no 'info' in the -D property) to match what I had in build.gradle:
`gradle test -Doverride.test.testLogging.showStandardStreams=true`

The answer from @guido-flohr worked well enough though