# Gradle: How to get output from test STDERR/STDOUT into console?

Tags: testing, gradle, stdout, stderr

(Gradle 3.2.1) I run some java tests, which logs output in Stderr/Stdout. I can see that output, if I start

```
gradle test --info
```

but in that case, much of unwanted output from 3-rd party libraries is there too.

[Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:external_tools) suggests using `logging.caputureStandardError / logging.caputureStandardError (loglevel)`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
   logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.QUIET
   logging.captureStandardError LogLevel.QUIET
}
```

Then if running `gradle test`, not STDERR/STDOUT is output in console.

How can I get just the output from the tests classes in console?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Add these lines to `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
    dependsOn cleanTest
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Notice: `dependsOn cleanTest` is not necessary but ***if not used***, you need to run `cleanTest` or `clean` task before `test` task.

---

### Edit:

A better approach:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
    testLogging {
        outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Notice: `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` is not necessary but ***if not used***, you need to run `cleanTest` or `clean` task before `test` task.

For more info and options see [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer).

Comment: @Omid Is there a way to do this on the command line. I may not want to edit my `build.gradle` file, and temporarily want to see the standard streams. Can I do something like `-Dtest.testLogging.showStandardStreams=true`?

Comment: @Kilokahn I thinks based on [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442642/how-do-i-set-test-testlogging-showstandardstreams-to-true-from-the-command-line), the answer is no.

Comment: Actually, one solution to change Gradle behavior while keeping `build.gradle` unchanged are initialization scripts. You can even check for project or system properties there to check whether the configuration of a test task should be changed.

Comment: Where did you find info about the `outputs` option? I don't see it in the documentation you linked.

Comment: This doesn't do anything in IntelliJ (JUnitPlatform)

Comment: Using `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }` is [not best practice, according to Gradle](https://blog.gradle.org/stop-rerunning-tests). If the tests are dependent on a variable, then [register as a task input](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs). If you want to re-run the tests, you can add [`--rerun` in Gradle 7.6](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:builtin_task_options)

Answer (score 32):

For those using Kotlin/Kotlin DSL for Gradle, you need to put the following in your `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    this.testLogging {
        this.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Also as mentioned in another answer, you will need to run `gradle clean test` for the output to print every time.

Comment: Thanks man. It's so hard to find the Kotlin DSL equivalents of Gradle code.

Comment: `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` can be added to the above response to avoid running `gradle clean test`. Just `gradle test` should work

Answer (score 1):

The `testLogging` answer is correct.  For me, since I already had a `tasks.test` section, I figured it'd be easier to put it there instead.

```kotlin
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    this.testLogging {
        this.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Talha Malik solution's above (and the ones in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356543/logging-while-testing-through-gradle/73207770#73207770)), when dealing with a multi-module android app the following can be used (root `build.gradle`)

```
// Call from root build.gradle
setupTestLogging()

fun Project.setupTestLogging() {
    for (sub in subprojects) {
        sub.tasks.withType<Test> {
            testLogging {
                exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(note that while `exceptionFormat` alone should be enough to get the wanted outcome, the `events("standardOut" ...)` mentioned above can be specified in the same way)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here, but wanted to add an alternative for anyone else that comes looking:

```
  test {
        onOutput { descriptor, event ->
                 logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
        }
  }
```

This helps distinguish output between tests when you are running multiple tests

Got this from gradle's official documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html