# How to redirect to stdoutt/stderror output from any process called by any gradle task, not necessarily test task

Tags: gradle

The [quite standard questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954017/gradle-how-to-get-output-from-test-stderr-stdout-into-console)n about gradle is how to make it possible to redirect output from launched process, to which the standard answer is to configure your tests like this:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

What I do miss in this answer - is how to print to the stdout/stderr when it's not about tests but about any arbitrary gradle task launched. In other words, I want to be able to see the standard output of any process called by gradle.

Comment: That should already happen by default as Gradle redirects standard output to the QUIET log level and standard error to the ERROR level. With no logging options, you are running Gradle at the LIFECYCLE level, which includes the former. Can you give an example where that is not the case?