# Can't see traces in Spock test

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spock

I'm trying to put traces into a Spock test to see how the PostgreSQL container was created by the testcontainer. But neither with log4j , nor with prints on the standard output nor by extending the Spec with a routine I can do it. The test code is as follows::

```
package com.makobrothers.mako.rrhh.persona.infrastructure.controller

import com.makobrothers.mako.IntegrationTest
import com.makobrothers.mako.MakoApplication
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.spock.Testcontainers
import spock.lang.Shared;
import spock.lang.Specification

import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
import org.json.simple.JSONObject


@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
    classes = MakoApplication.class
)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
//@Sql(scripts = ["classpath:/createTablePersona.sql", "classpath:/insertTablePersona.sql"])
class PersonaRestAssuredSpec extends Specification {
    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonaRestAssuredSpec.class)
    final static POSTGRES_TEST_IMAGE = "postgres:15.1"
    final static Random RANDOM = new Random();
    public static PostgreSQLContainer staticPostgreSQL = new PostgreSQLContainer(POSTGRES_TEST_IMAGE)
            .withDatabaseName("makoTest")
            .withUsername("mako")
            .withPassword("mako")
            .withExposedPorts(5432)
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier({ cmd -> cmd.withName('postgreSQL-' + ( RANDOM.nextInt() & Integer.MAX_VALUE )) })

    @Shared
    public PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = staticPostgreSQL
      
    @Value('\${server.http.port}')
    private int port

    def setup() throws Exception {
        RestAssured.port = port
        log.info("Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
        log.warn("Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
        log.error("Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
        showTrace "Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()
        showTrace "DatabaseName: " + postgreSQLContainer.getDatabaseName()
        showTrace "Username: " + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername()
        showTrace "Password: " + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()
        showTrace "Port: " + postgreSQLContainer.getBoundPortNumbers()
    }
    
    def "showConfigTest"() {
        given: "A client request to test findById"
            log.info("Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
            log.warn("Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
            log.error("Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl())
            showTrace "Url: " + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()
            int left = 2
            int right = 2
        when: "Nothing"
            int result = left + right
        then: "Nothing"
            assert result == 4
    }
    
}
```

I have extended Spec with a method to print (SpockConfig.groovy) as I saw an example in another query:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class LabelPrinter {
    def showTrace(def message) {
        println message
        true
    }
}

Specification.mixin LabelPrinter
```

And the gradle part is declared with:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED", "STANDARD_OUT", "STANDARD_ERROR"
    }
    
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.test.output
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

The output is allways the same:

```
$ gradle clean test

> Task :test

  com.makobrothers.mako.rrhh.persona.infrastructure.controller.PersonaRestAssuredSpec

    ✔ showConfigTest (5.5s)
  1 passing (1m 15s)


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 27s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

Comment: Do either of these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9356543/4161471 https://stackoverflow.com/q/40954017/4161471

Comment: I have also tried modifying the tests part of gradle as follows:`code`test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

 testLogging {
  outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
  showStandardStreams = true
  events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED", "STANDARD_OUT", "STANDARD_ERROR"
 }
 
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.test.output
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
    }
}`code` 
But I still can't see the traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to gradle and now it works:

```
testlogger {
    // pick a theme - mocha, standard, plain, mocha-parallel, standard-parallel or plain-parallel
    theme 'mocha'
    // set to false to disable detailed failure logs
    showExceptions true
    // set threshold in milliseconds to highlight slow tests
    slowThreshold 2000
    // displays a breakdown of passes, failures and skips along with total duration
    showSummary true
    // set to false to hide passed tests
    showPassed true
    // set to false to hide skipped tests
    showSkipped true
    // set to false to hide failed tests
    showFailed true
    // enable to see standard out and error streams inline with the test results
    showStandardStreams true
    // set to false to hide passed standard out and error streams
    showPassedStandardStreams true
    // set to false to hide skipped standard out and error streams
    showSkippedStandardStreams true
    // set to false to hide failed standard out and error streams
    showFailedStandardStreams true
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
        showStandardStreams = true
        events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED", "STANDARD_OUT", "STANDARD_ERROR"
    }
    
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.test.output
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

I think it is the showStandardStreams property that allows the logs to be seen.

Comment: Be aware that using `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }` is not best practice, [according to Gradle](https://blog.gradle.org/stop-rerunning-tests), and I recommend removing it. If the tests are dependent on a variable, then [register it as a task input](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs). If you want to re-run the tests, you can add [--rerun in Gradle 7.6](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:builtin_task_options). Otherwise, if there's no output, just enjoy the extra time that Gradle's saved you!