# How to show failed values on test junit 5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

Have a Spring Boot project with Spring test, jUnit5 and 100 tests, but fails only one in a large flow, replicating the problem manually would be a very lengthy and tedious task. Is there a way to display the expected value and the failed value when using assertThat?, by example:

```java
assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

If it fails I would like to see in the command console the original response value from the http server.

From my build.gradle configuration files I indicated that all the items that have been executed and their results should be shown:

```
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

But I would also like to see the content of what failed to correct where applicable only:

```bash
$ ./gradlew test
> Task :test
DemoControllerTest > test1() PASSED
DemoControllerTest > test2() PASSED
...
DemoControllerTest > test88() PASSED
DemoControllerTest > test99() FAILED
...
```

I want to see why test 99 failed, what was the response message from the server, if it was a 500 or 404 or 403 error, etc. I would like the same for the rest of the text type verifications, for example to evaluate the http response bodies.

Comment: [assertEquals](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-byte-byte-java.lang.String-)

Comment: How are you running these tests? In your IDE, the results will probably show up in a window somewhere. Command line or on CI? Then you'll probably need to look at JUnit's result XML file. CI tools like Jenkins have built-in options for that.

Comment: @Jorn I use cli from bash on linux, and use gradle configuration files. @jhamon i try use `withFailMessage` but the custom text is not show.

Comment: Gradle will produce a file with the test results. You can configure which files and where they end up in the Gradle `test` task.

Comment: @Jorn yes, when add `showCauses`, `showExceptions` and `showStackTraces` in `build.gradle` appears the `expected` and `but was` values, but only in the xml report file. Is it possible for this to appear in the terminal as well? so you don't have to open multiple files every time errors are generated.

Comment: I think Gradle is to blame here, not JUnit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954017/gradle-how-to-get-output-from-test-stderr-stdout-into-console

Comment: Thanks @Robert, i solve this using `outputs.upToDateWhen` and `showStandardStreams` :)